# Sample PDF with embedded flash video?

Tags: c#, .net, flash, pdf

Does anyone know where i can view a sample PDF that has an embedded flash video? I know it's silly to ask because you would think any tech-oriented user should be able to find one using Google but I really could not.

Another question I have is, how hard would it be to embed a flash video into a PDF file using an API in C#? One possible requirement I may have is to generate a PDF on the fly with all required content available at hand (ie: text, images and potentially video).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here from Technology Review, TR 35

http://www.technologyreview.com/TR35/Profile.aspx?trid=688

http://www.technologyreview.com/files/20747/TR35_Dries_Buytaert.pdf?download&track

Comment: hope you found the link adequate?

Comment: Both links are dead so this answer is completely outdated

Answer (score 1):

AlivePDF is worth a look if you're working with PDF's in flash http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pdflatex](http://www.latex-project.org/) to generate the pdf's on the fly and using the [movie15 package](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/movie15/doc/) embed the flash video (or other types of video). An example with embedded video is [here](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/movie15/doc/overlay-example.pdf).

[iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/) is Java library with C# port for pdf generation and it appears possible to [embed flash](http://consult.goannatravel.com/blog/2008/05/04/embedding-flexflash-into-pdf/).