# Embedding video/flash in PDF using php

Tags: php, pdf, video, pdf-generation, video-embedding

Is it possible to dynamically embed `video(any format)/ flash` into `PDF` using **php**?

I found this [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889371/sample-pdf-with-embedded-flash-video?rq=1), but not useful.
Also I googled but didn't find a satisfying answer to my question that

Whether it is possible or not (with the help of php libraries)?
And if yes, what are the side-effects of embeding video in PDF?

Plz help me to get into right direction

Comment: sorry but i have no idea how this possibly. PDF is text format and can't contain a video

Comment: It can contain a video, and it is possible to embed video in PDF using Acrobat 9
But I need to do that dynamically i.e using any pdf generating library(php)

Comment: save this [PDF](http://demo.cosolvent.com/ccs/main.php?g2_view=core.DownloadItem&g2_itemId=4c6ab7055d84c) and then click on play

Comment: maybe this only acrobat feature? I can't play video :( I see just static image.

Comment: uhh you need Adobe Reader version 9 for it to work and also you need to save the PDF file to your system

Comment: Not sure, however you might have some luck using the flash object tag and `DOMPDF` https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Answer (score 0):

You should consider that every user might not use Adobe. Ex- I personally use foxit reader and then it will be nightmare when users are not getting what they were told.So better go with some other way to you might embed video in email or something.